# Where is the configuration for the actions that appear in GNOME/Cinnamon's start menu search results

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, gnome, cinnamon

I've been looking for some time now for a way to turn off my computer with a combination of keys, without the need to confirm, or with a simple key confirmation (ex. pressing Enter).

I have a Tuxedo computer with recommended OS, I think it is a mixture of GNOME, Cinnamon and Budgie, I know those are not exactly the same thing but part of the problem is I don't know who's the owner of something specific.

This was for context, and I now it may seem that it deviates from my problem, but now I really want to learn when I press the super key to start a menu and I start typing, where do the search menu results come from?

[Screenshot of search results from start menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uopTm.png)

The first, "Applications", is from applications installed. The second "Application Actions" is from the desktop files that exist in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`. Where can I find info about the third menu "Actions"?